# site-collection with web parts already on it in sharepoint online like templates from 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to have a site-collection created with web parts already loaded on it? Much like templates from 2013? Currently I have built a JSON template for all the document libraries, lists, etc.. I am looking to build a template for the web parts but can it be done through powershell, azure, etc?

I would prefer not to use the "Save site as a template" that is hidden.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to build a template for modern web parts, consider using PnP Provisioning Engine from PnP PowerShell modules.
See a reference here: [Web/Site Templates in SharePoint Online Modern Pages? No problem.](https://rasper87.wordpress.com/2019/03/13/web-site-templates-in-sharepoint-online-modern-pages-no-problem/)

For classic web parts, here is one option to use Visual Studio: [Create web parts for SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/creating-web-parts-for-sharepoint?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online, you may want to investigate using the [PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning). The example uses a site design to apply a PnP provisioning template to a site.